# Stuck Build for wating for finish

Tags: android-studio

I imported a project in android studio and after open project and I chose layout design the interface is stuck in Build.

[image]

Comment: Grammatical cleanup and brought image inline

Answer (score 0):

Try invalidate cache and restart option in file dropdown